# Permitir solo números enteros y float en un input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc, razor

En el `Modal` tengo el precio de tipo float, (anteriormente tenia un `input type=number`, pero al tener el precio como float, no lo mostraba en el input cuando cargaba la pagina), por lo que decidí cambiarlo por un `input text`. Necesito validar con `jquery` que en ese input text el usuario no pueda poner un precio ficticio(con símbolos, espacios en blanco etc..) obligarlo a que solo pueda poner el precio como entero o decimal.

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label>Precio:</label>               
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_price" name="txt_price" value="@Model.Precio" required />
</div>
```

Comment: Es absolutamente necesario que sea en Jquery?. Saludos

Comment: gracias @Daniel por contestar!, y cual seria la otra alternativa?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no se mostraba el float porque era `input type=number`? Los input de tipo numérico soportan decimales sin problemas (y serían la mejor opción en este caso). ¿Cuál es el problema exacto que ves al usarlos? ¿Cuál es el valor que pones en el campo?

Comment: @Claudio jQuery es una biblioteca de JavaScript, esto podría solucionarse usando JavaScript sin necesidad de usar jQuery, o incluso simplemente con HTML sin más.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionarlo elegí otra alternativa mas fácil que jquery. Utilice una expresión regular en el input text.

```html
<input type="text"  pattern="^[0-9]{0,12}([,][0-9]{2,2})?$" class="form-control" id="txt_price" name="txt_price" value="@Model.Precio" required />
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que utilices el RegEx y lo verifiques con un JS , ya que en caso contrario con solo hacer inspeccionar elemento y eliminar el `pattern` del input ya podrian enviarte sin problema un valor distinto , saludos.

Comment: ¡Ahm, estás poniendo una coma! Por eso no te funciona el campo de tipo `number`. El separador de decimales del campo es con un punto (`.`), no con coma (`,`). Si cambias ese punto por una coma, podrás usar el campo de tipo numérico sin problemas.

Comment: @Daniel igual que el usuario puede inspeccionar el código y quitar el pattern del input, también puede deshabilitar la función JS que utiliza la expresión regular para verificar el valor. Esa segunda verificación debería hacerse en el lado del servidor, no del cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Puede utilizar el input type "number" para evitar que se ingresas o otro caracteres, te recomiendo visitar la pagina: [input number](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) para saber más del tema

Como bien lo comentaron anteriormente con inspeccionar el elemento y eliminar el pattern del input, se enviar los datos del formulario, te recomiendo hacer una validación del lado del servidor con la función "preg_match" en php. te recomiendo visitar la pagina: [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) para saber más del tema

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label>Precio:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="0.0" step="any" pattern="[0-9,.]+" required>
</div>
```